# Equivalent jquery code for existing javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I wrote one javascript method and will be called on click of an anchor.

```
onclick="return show('contentTwo','content');
```

here `contentTwo` and `content` are div Ids.

### method:

```
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
```

Now I would like to use jquery's `slideDown` and `slideUp` methods than using javascript. how can I convert the above code into jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything, where exactly are you stuck? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: This can easily be accomplished by doing a Google search. Please try yourself, this way you can learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function show(shown, hidden) {
  $('#' + shown).show();
  $('#' + hidden).hide();
  return false;
}
```

or

```
function show(shown, hidden) {
  $('#' + shown + ',' + '#' + hidden).toggle();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#shown, #hidden").slideToggle("slow");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rekQ9/53/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

DEMO `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/YFmtc/2/

```
$("#hidden").hide();
$('a').click(function(){
        $("#shown, #hidden").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

See API [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)